# angular 2 webpack how to refer to local js library without using npm package

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I thought this is easy, but I am lost.

I am using webpack to build an angular 2 application, and in the index.html, I added this:

```
<script src="./react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script src="./react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jnpr-vendors.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jnpr-components.min.js"></script>
```

all these js file is in the same directory as index.html file.

But when I use webpack dev server, I got 404 error for all these files:

http://localhost:3002/jnpr-components.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Obviously, the external js file is not being put into dist/ directory, which is as belows for the webpack config:

```
output : {
    path : helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath : 'http://localhost:3002/',
    filename : '[name].js',
    chunkFilename : '[id].chunk.js'
  },
```

I even created a folder 'dist' and put these js libraries in that folder, still can not be found.

I remember web-pack-server is using in memory directory for the js files. But now how can I refer to some local files in development environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell `webpack-dev-server` where to serve static files from, you can use [`devServer.contentBase`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase). By default it's the current directory.

For instance if your libraries are in the directory `assets` (relative to the webpack config), the configuration would look like this:

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using angular-cli.
If so then you need to put your JS file in assets directory.
Then use it in the index.html as follows.

```
assets/your-file.js
```

Because webpack only allow those files to be served which are in the assets folder or defined as assets in angular-cli.json.